# A very common mechanics question with a little challenge

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mass

I was trying to refresh my knowledge on classical mechanics by myself and I wanted to solve the well known two masses attached together by a string through a hole on a horizontal surface example. One mass on the the surface m1 and other mass hanging down from the hole m2. I wanted to attach the hanging mass to the ground by a spring and only considered the extension length. I tired to identify forces on both masses and I got lost. I found that the total foce on the horizontal surface mass m1 is spring force plus the weight of the hanging mass m2 i.e. m2g. However, I can't find the force on the hanging mass. I dared to say that it is only its own weight but when I apply D'Alembert's approach and then Lagrangian approach I get an extra m2g. The only case which makes both results the same is hanging mass m2 is balanced i.e. total force on it is zero. I don't think this is ture. Maybe it is but I can't see it. What do you think? What is the total force on the hanging mass?

[image: Here's the diagram]

Comment: I think that for questions like this that it really helps to present a clear, labeled diagram of the problem.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I tried to add a diagram. I hope it is a little bit more clear now.

Comment: The force on the hanging mass is the sum of the spring force, the tension of the string, and gravity. But these problems are precisely the ones for which the Lagrangian approach was made: Newton's laws are tricky here.

Comment: Is there any motion here, or is it a static, balanced system?

Comment: @Dlamini It does not say anything but probably, the mass on the table moves towards the hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I present analysis using newtonian mechanics.

**Static solution:** When a forces equilibrium is achieved, this becomes a statics problem.

Forces on $m_1$ are: sliding friction and the tension of the string:
$$m_1g\mu - T_{string} = 0 \tag1$$

where $g$ is gravitational acceleration, $\mu$ is the coefficient of static friction between the surface and $m_1$, and $T$ is the tension in the string.

Forces on the hanging mass:
$$T_{string} - m_2g -kx = 0 \tag2$$
If the spring is extended beyond its natural length, it will pull down on the mass, so that tension in the string is above the weight ($m_2g$) of the mass. If the spring is compressed due to $m_2$ pressing on it, then it is holing the mass up to some extent, and tension in the string is less than the weight of $m_2$.

If you would like to set up such an equilibrium, it is of course trickier than defining the equilibrium. I would:

1. Find the limit of the frictional force between $m_1$ and the table. This is the force at which $m_1$ starts to slide if pulled along the surface.
2. Choose $m_2$ so that its weight is less than the frictional force limit calculated in step 1 above, otherwise it will slide. Alternatively, you will have to make sure your spring is in compression if $m_2g$ exceeds $m_1g\mu$.
3. Choose a spring with stiffness $k$ and natural length so as to ensure that its length difference when spanning the ground and $m_2$ will ensure that the sum of $m_2$'s mass and the spring force will keep $m_1$ from sliding off the surface.

**Constant motion solution:** This is similar to the static solution but for minor modifications. Firstly, friction in equation 1 will be kinetic friction, not static. Equations 1 and 2 will remain valid, assuming an instantaneous forces.

**Solution with acceleration:** In this case, the accelerating forces have to be included. Equation $1$ (the forces on $m_1$)  changes to:
$$m_1g\mu_{kinetic} + m_1a -T_{string} = 0\tag3$$
where $a$ is the acceleration of $m_1$ and $m_2$ (connected by the string). In other words, the string tension (caused by the weight of $m_2$ and the pull of the spring) must be high enough to overcome sliding friction and cause acceleration of $m_1$ towards $m_2$. Equation 2 (the forces on $m_2$) becomes:
$$T_{string} - m_2g - m_2a -kx = 0 \tag4$$
An extended spring increases the tension-increasing effect of the weight of $m_2$, increasing string tension. A compressed spring decreases string tension. When the upward force of a compressed spring is equal to the weight of $m_2$, string tension is zero.